# Mma 10.2 `Alphabet` and `LanguageData` give different and both erroneous list of letters

Tags: bugs, string-manipulation, curated-data

**Bug introduced in 10.2 and fixed in 10.3**

---

The new function [`Alphabet`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Alphabet.html) introduced in Mathematica 10.2 gives the wrong list of letters for the Spanish language in my system (Windows 7 64 bits).

```
Alphabet[Entity["Language", "Spanish"]]
```

> ```
> {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "l", "m", "n", "ñ", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "z"}
> ```

That list is missing `{"j", "k", "w", "x", "y"}` and special characters.

The list provided by [`LanguageData`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LanguageData.html) its also wrong

```
LanguageData["Spanish", "Letters"]
```

> ```
> {"a", "á", "b", "c", "d", "e", "é", "f", "g", "h", "i", "í", "j", "l", "m", "n", "ñ", "o", "ó", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "ú", "ü", "v", "x", "y", "z"}
> ```

as its missing `{"k","w"}`.

Can anybody reproduce this behaviour in other systems and other languages?

I have filed a report with Wolfram Technical Support [*CASE:3388733*]

The correct list as given by the [Spanish Royal Academy of Language](http://www.rae.es/consultas/exclusion-de-ch-y-ll-del-abecedario) is

> a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m, n, ñ, o, p, q, r, s, t, u, v,
>   w, x, y, z.

Comment: I'm in the process of installing 10.2 presently, but in 10.1, `LanguageData["Spanish", "Letters"]` produces the same result you get, which is missing `k` and `w`

Comment: I get this in 10.2 too, so I will be adding the "bugs" tag, as we have sufficient confirmation this is a bug.

Comment: It's a bug, and it's being looked into.

Comment: You can use `LanguageData["Spanish", "BasicAlphabet"]` while it gets fixed.

Answer (score 3):

*Just an extended comment:*

The **problem seems not to be fixed in v11.1.1 for other "latin" alphabet based languages**. Here are some differences between what is returned by `Alphabet` and `LanguageData[lang, "Letters"]` for some european countries.

`Alphabet` seems to do OK, but the problem is that `"Letters"` do not always include at least all characters returned by `Alphabet` (below in red).

```
({#, Grid@
   List@(SequenceAlignment @@ 
      StringJoin /@ 
       Sort /@ {Alphabet[#], 
         LanguageData[#, "Letters"]})} & /@ {"Czech", "Danish", 
 "Dutch", "Finnish", "French", "German", "Hungarian", "Italian", 
 "Polish", "Portuguese", "Romanian", "Slovak", "Slovenian", 
 "Spanish", "Swedish"} // Grid[#, Frame -> All] &) /. {expr : {_, ""} :> Style[expr, Red, Bold], expr : {"", _} :> Style[expr, Blue, Bold]}
```

[image]

For example, here is what is returned for "Danish":

```
Sort /@ {Alphabet[#], LanguageData[#, "Letters"]} &@"Danish" // Column
```

> [image: Blockquote]

where you can see `"q","w","x","z"` are not returned by `LanguageData` as indicated in red in the table above.

Comment: Have you reported this?

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov No, never done that. Please do so if you can. By the way, the problem with the missing letters is that this propagates to other `LanguageData` properties like "LetterFrequency" where these letters are also missing...

Answer (score 2):

This was reported to Wolfram Technical Support [CASE:3388733] and acknowledged as a bug.

The problem was fixed in *Mathematica 10.3*.

```
Alphabet[Entity["Language", "Spanish"]]
```

> ```
> {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "ñ", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"}
> ```

```
LanguageData["Spanish", "Letters"]
```

> ```
> {"a", "á", "b", "c", "d", "e", "é", "f", "g", "h", "i", "í", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "ñ", "o", "ó", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "ú", "ü", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"}
> ```